# Delete git reference

Tags: git

**edit**: Branch has already been deleted, not a duplicate of the linked question. Prune answer below was the answer.

**Original**

I pushed a branch to remote that I would like to delete. I proceeded to delete the branch. So the branch is no longer there.

```
git branch -r
  origin/develop
  origin/master
```

My local branches also has it removed.

```
git branch 
* develop
  master
```

However, if I do an ls-remote, it shows up.

```
git ls-remote
From git@<address>:<project>.git
<hash>  HEAD
<hash>  refs/heads/develop
<hash>  refs/heads/master
<hash>  refs/heads/portmapping
<hash>  refs/tags/3.1.3
```

The reference in question is portmapping. It's the branch I deleted, but it's showing up as a reference still. How do I remove this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-to-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cleanup remote deleted branch.

```
$ git remote prune origin
```